# Apache port being automatically forwarded

Tags: apache, freebsd

I'm trying to have two different directory associated to two different ports. (8001 and 8004), but whenever I try to access port 8004 in a browser, it redirects automatically to port 8001.

Here's some extract of the config files that seems relevant:

In `httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8001
Listen 8004
```

Removed comment to line:

```
Include etc/apache24/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In file `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
  DocumentRoot "<path_to_site_1>"

  <Directory "<path_to_site_1>">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory "<path_to_site_1>">
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8004>
  DocumentRoot "path_to_site_2"

  <Directory "path_to_site_2">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory "path_to_site_2">
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's a list of things I've tried, that didn't change anything:

- Having the VirtualHost declaration in httpd.conf
- Changing the order of the Virtual host declaration
- Changing port 8004 to another port
- Clear the browser cache and try a different browser

If I comment `Listen 8001`, it breaks everything. 
Port 80 seems to point to the default www directory of this FreeBSD installation and still works properly, for phpMyAdmin is installed there and is still accessible.

Maybe of note, it's a FreeBSD installation running on Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Thank you for any help or ideas to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in this case, the comportment wasn't due to Apache configuration but to the website installations. One was a WordPress installation and the other was a Drupal installation. I wasn't aware that by moving those website in the directory structure, they would no longer point at the right place. WordPress was doing the redirection.

The issue was solved with two different solution, one for each platform.

For WordPress:

In the file `functions.php`, located in the theme directory:

1. Add the following lines:

   ```
   update_option( 'siteurl', '<new_url>' );
   update_option( 'home', '<new_url>' );
   ```
2. In the browser, fefresh the website a few time
3. Remove both lines from the file

For Drupal:

(using drush) In the directory where the website is located:

```
drush cache-rebuild
```

The combination of both commands solved the issue with both installation.